# Discrete Math sets and equality.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question about sets  and subsets.

Consider the universe $\mathbb{Z}$ comprising of all integers and with the following sets:

$A=\{2m+1\}$

$B=\{2n-3\}$,

where $m$ and $n$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.

In my book it says $A=B$, but whenever I plugin values it doesn't equal. How do I remake the formula inside set $B$ so it pops up a same number as $A$?

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ fixed? I think you mean the sets $\{2m+1:m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{2n-3:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, in which case they both contain all odd integers and whence are the same.

Comment: m=n in this case

Comment: No, $m$ and $n$ vary. They both run over all elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ in their respective set.

Comment: So if for example set B contained even jntegers then A wont equal B right?

Comment: Yes, but then $B$ can be written like $\{2n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. So, $n$ goes through all integers, is then multiplied by $2$ and the resulting value is in the set. Hence all elements of the set will be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the sets are equal, you need to show that $x \in A \implies x \in B$ and $x \in B \implies x \in A$

If $x \in A$ then $x = 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$. Let $m = n-2$. Then 
$x = 2(n-2) + 1 = 2n - 3$. Hence $x \in B$.

You should be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

All it says is that both A and B give you the set of all odd integers. To see them being the same, choose n = m + 2.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but how did you come to the concllusion of settinf n to m+2?

Comment: 2m+1 = 2n-3. Solve this for n: 2n = 2m+4. So n = m+2.

Comment: Thanks, real life saver, now I can solve the rest of the questions.